# How to save String as JSONB type in postgres when using AWS Glue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, jsonb

I'm seeking a solution on how to write string as jsonb type in postgresql. So DynamicFrame has a string column that holds json data. When trying to save to postgres

```
DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = Transform0, database = "cms", table_name = "cms_public_listings", transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
```

I get the following error:

An error was encountered:

```
An error occurred while calling o1623.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 134.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 134.0 (TID 137, ip-172-31-27-18.ec2.internal, executor 24): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "public".listings ([REMOVED_COLUMNS]) VALUES ([REMOVED_VALUES]) was aborted: ERROR: column "schema" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 207  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

I can't change the schema to hold a string, so it is either I use AWS Glue ETL or would have to craft Python Shell Job. I would prefer to find a way to use PySpark with AWS Glue.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use native spark dataframe, because it allows me more customization.I can use **stringtype** property to cast json field from dataframe to jsonb field in the table. For this case, my dataframe has two fields.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf())
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read.format('csv') \
               .option('delimiter','|') \
               .option('header','True') \
               .load('your_path') 

##some transformation...

url = 'jdbc:postgresql://your_host:5432/your_databasename'
properties = {'user':'*****',
              'password':'*****',
              'driver': "org.postgresql.Driver",
              'stringtype':"unspecified"}
        
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table='your_tablename', mode='append', properties=properties)
```

Before to execute the above script, you should create the table in postgresql, because the property **mode** is setted as **append**. This as follow:

```
create table your_tablename
(
    my_json_field jsonb,
    another_field int
)
```