# Problem writting an enun on PostgreSQL using a PySpark Dataframe with jdbc write

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

So I am moving data from a MySQL (5.7) database to a PostgreSQL (12.7) one using PySpark (Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12). A table from the destiny model has an column that is an Enum.

```
CREATE TYPE ORDER_STATUS AS ENUM (
'SHIPPED','PAID','REFUNDED','PARTIALLY_REFUNDED','PROCESSING');
```

When inserting:

```
df_orders.select(df_orders.columns).write.format('jdbc').options(**postgres_write_opts_table).mode('append').save()
```

I am getting the next exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "status" is of type order_status but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Basically I need to cast the column status to `ORDER_STATUS` . I have tried to use a `UserDefinedType` (PySpark does no have `SQLUserDefinedType`) but no really knowing what I am doing because the documentation is not very clear.

```
class StatusUDT(UserDefinedType):
@classmethod
def sqlType(self):
    return NullType()

@classmethod
def module(cls):
    return cls.__module__

def serialize(self, obj):
    return f"{obj.value}::order_status_type"

def deserialize(self, datum):
    return {x.value: x for x in Some}[datum]
```

And then I try the casting

```
df_orders = df_orders.withColumn("status", col("status").cast(StatusUDT()))
```

Then I am getting the next error then:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`status` AS NULL)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to null;;
```

Is there any way to cast this Enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally was able to overcome this issue. I temporally removed the Enum so I could keep doing more tests and then I had a similar issue with a JSON type.
Searching about it I found this post: [How to save String as JSONB type in postgres when using AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734872/how-to-save-string-as-jsonb-type-in-postgres-when-using-aws-glue) . And I fixed it setting the property:

```
'stringtype':"unspecified"
```

as the post answer suggests.

Then I put back the Enum into the table and this property also worked. I was able to run the insertions with no further issues.

Comment: This answer seems to work fine, when all the values in the column are not null. However, if some of the value are nullable, the same error as mentioned in the question description is raised. Any ideas how to make this work with NULLs as well?