# Issue with PostreSQL Enum when writing an AWS Glue DynamicFrame with JDBC write

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to write an AWSGlue DynamicFrame in a PostgreSQL database with a JDBC write. The destination table includes one column of type `Enum`.

I start by selecting the columns of interest from the underlying PySpark DataFrame and then convert the DataFrame to a DynamicFrame:

```
# Select columns of interest
final_df = df.select("id", "my_struct.*")

# Convert back to DynamicFrame
dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(final_df, context, "final_dyf")
```

The insert is done using the following code:

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dyf,
    connection_type="postgresql",
    connection_options={
        "url": "jdbc:postgresql://my_db_url",
        "user": POSTGRES_USER,
        "password": POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        "dbtable": table_name,
        "stringtype": "unspecified",
    },
    transformation_ctx=f"write_dyf_to_{table_name}_table",
)
```

When inserting my data I received the following error message:

```
ERROR: column "x" is of type x_enum but expression is of type character.
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I had a look at this post: [Problem writting an enun on PostgreSQL using a PySpark Dataframe with jdbc write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263214/problem-writting-an-enun-on-postgresql-using-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-jdbc-write) which highlights the same problem. The suggested answer recommends adding `"stringtype": "unspecified"` in the JDBC connection options.

I did it but I am still having the issue. I am suspecting that the problem comes from the fact that in this particular case the whole column `x` is `NULL`. The enum column in the PostgreSQL table is `NULLABLE`.

I have found a workaround using `DropNullFields.apply` but I would like to avoid doing this if possible.

Has anyone faced this issue previously or has any suggestions?

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you face is that Postgres is very strictly typed. This means variables must be of the data type as declared. (Yes, Postgres will attempt some implicit conversions, but it is generally a bad plan to depend upon them.) It is generally much safer to Cast to the correct data type. Even though NULL is valid for virtually any data type it does not automatically become the type needed. I do not know your particular obscurification dialect so will provide SQL directly for the casting. There are two methods: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b584163c471ac606dd1c32708a768103))

1. The Postgres cast operator.  From::To
2. The SQL sandard cast dunction. Cast(From as To)

You should be able to incorporate one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware of the Cast operator from Postgres but I am not sure of how to use it in PySpark. I will have a look and see how I can try it.